# Vertical centering of multiple variable sized images in a div with CSS in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, vertical-alignment

I've seen and read numerous posts on this subject but none worked in my environment or I did something wrong. I have a div that contains images and text of various unknown sizes. I want all the images and in the div to be vertically centered. I'm using Internet Explorer 9.

Here is my code, I'm removed all the various techniques I've attempted for the sake of simplicity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div.header
{
height:75px;
background-color:#FFF;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
div.headerleft
{
border: none; 
float: left; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}

div.headerright
{
border: none; 
float: right; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}
h1
{
font: 44px Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0; 
padding-top: 0;
}   

img.centerImage
{
vertical-align:middle;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerleft">
        <img class="centerImage" border="0" alt="Test 1" src="../Images/test1.jpg" />
        <img class="centerImage" border="0" alt="Test 2" src="../Images/test2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="headerright">
        <h1>
            Centered Text Vertically
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to emphasize that the text and images are of unknown sizes. I've found this certainly complicates the solution. Also, based on ActiveX requirements, I'm using Internet Explorer version 9. Any advice out there? Thanks!

Comment: You say unknown sizes, but have set the header to height: 75px;, which is it?

Comment: @reisio 75px is the height of the containing div, all images are less that 75px in height ... that I do know.

Answer (score 1):

To use vertical alignment, you are better off setting a wrapper with the display set to table-cell:

See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eNXzp/)

**THE CSS:**

```
/* the vertical alignment class */
.centerImage {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**THE HTML**

```
...
<div class="headerleft">
  <span class="centerImage">
    <img border="0" alt="Test 1" src="path_to_image.jpg" />
  </span>
  <span class="centerImage">
    <img border="0" alt="Test 2" src="path_to_image.jpg" />
  </span>
</div>
<div class="headerright">
  <h1 class="centerImage">Centered Text Vertically</h1>
</div>
...
```

**Tested:**

IE9, IE8, OPERA, SAFARI, FIREFOX, K-MELEON, GOOGLE CHROME

**Notes:**

You should specify the image width and height to a proper HTML validation and to allow a better understanding by the browser.

**Read More About This:**

[CSS Display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)  |  [CSS vertical-align property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)  |  [CSS Tricks: What is vertical Align?](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

---

## EDITED

In regards to the comment given by reisio, to have the same vertical point to the images on the left and the text on the right, we can go with a more simple solution:

See the [Fiddle Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eNXzp/3/)

**RELEVANT CSS**

```
/* the trick you want */
.centerImage {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div.headerleft {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
}

div.headerright {
    border: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 44px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

**RELEVANT HTML**

```
<div class="headerleft">
  <img class="centerImage" border="0" alt="Test 1" src="path_to_img.jpg" />
  <img class="centerImage" border="0" alt="Test 2" src="path_to_img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="headerright">
  <h1 class="centerImage">Centered Text Vertically</h1>
</div>
```

For this solution, we use the vertical-align set to the img tag, and the line-height to create the same vertical-point and to align vertically the text.

**You can read:** [CSS line-height Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

## EDITED

If you can't set a `height` to the images, the only way to solve your issue is to use a bit of **JavaScript** to **dynamically** find the tallest image and apply that `height` to the `line-height` on the `H1` tag.

See this [working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eNXzp/4/)

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize the variable to 0
    var height = 0;

    // run by each image to find the tallest
    $('.headerleft img').each(function() {
        height = ($(this).outerHeight(true)>height) ? ($(this).outerHeight(true)) : height;
    });

    // vertical center the text
    $('.headerright h1').css({"line-height": height + "px"});
});
```

**Note:**
*Removed the `line-height` from the `div.headerleft` and `div.headerright` since it is not longer needed!*

Comment: I believe he wants the images on the left and the text on the right both aligned to the same vertical point.

Comment: reisio: I've added a few minutes ago a solution taking into consideration your comment! Seems to solve that issue!

Comment: Indeed it does, assuming he does in fact want a fixed vertical dimension of 75px despite his reiteration that he didn't (which is probably the case). I saw earlier and opted not to comment again, but if you want my agreement you have it sir. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. Unless I'm mistaken, this does not work with unknown image sizes. If I remove the width and heights it fails.

Comment: Adding more to my scenario, If I have 2 images in my headerleft div, then it works without specifying image sizes. If I have just 1 image, it is top justified.

Comment: Well, for the images with or without height defined, the solution works! the text is another type of problem... let me see if I can solve this quickly!

Comment: Well, there you have it: [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eNXzp/4/) Since you don't have the images `height`, with that bit of Jquery will find it dynamically and pass it on to the `H1` `line-height`. I've also edited my answer with this new solution!

Comment: Oh you definitely don't need JS.  display: table-cell; / vertical-align: middle; will take care of the images, and line-height will take care of the text.  Again, assuming he wants that 75px hard dimension.

Comment: He says that the amount of text is unclear! The images height and width isn't set! The amount of images is variable! With all of this, unless he uses actual tables with vertical alignment, he will not get a full cross browser support, thus the JS solution. _(take note that a pile of other solutions are present)_

Comment: I appreciate your solution, however, I was looking for a pure CSS solution. You've certainly helped me get closer to the answer in that it all worked (pre your JQuery) with the 2 image scenario. However, when I remov 1 of the images (leaving only one to center) if no longer aligns. And I do need that for only 1 image. I can't figure out why 1 image doesn't work but > 1 does. I guess I could add an invisible image of 1px50px. Kludge!

Comment: If you want the most flexibility, you'd want to set it up to use display: table/table-row/table-cell values with vertical-align: middle;.